# Convert NSInteger to NSIndexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsindexpath, nsinteger

Basically I am storing an index of an array in a NSInteger. I now need it as an NSIndexpath, I'm struggling to see and find a way to convert my NSInteger to NSIndexpath so I can reuse it.

Comment: What do you need the `NSIndexPath` for? Do you need it for a `UITableView`?

Comment: It's used when calling a update statement for sqlite. I think I now converted to NSIndexPath but I need NSIndexPath.row and this throws an error. Any ideas?

Comment: You can **not** call `row` on an index path created with `indexPathWithIndex:`. To create an index path you can call `row` on it, you can use `indexPathForRow:inSection:`.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

For an int `index`:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:index];
```

Creates Index of the item in node 0 to point to as per [the reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

To use the indexPath in a `UITableView`, the more appropriate method is

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I still do path.row or am I getting my eiders crossed?

Answer (score 8):

**If you need a `NSIndexPath` for a `UITableView`**, you can use `indexPathForRow:inSection:` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow%3ainSection%3a)). Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row. An index path created with `indexPathWithIndex:` only contains one index and won't work with a table view.

Answer (score 3):

Use  below methods of  [NSIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

```
+ (id)indexPathWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
+ (id)indexPathWithIndexes:(NSUInteger *)indexes length:(NSUInteger)length;
- (id)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Use as below and also Don't forget to `release` `myIndexPath` object after using.

```
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:[myIntObj intValue]];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3:**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
```