# How to convert int to nsindexpath?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsindexpath

I am making a basic quiz application.The choices are in the form of a table view. If the user moves to a previous question, I want to show him his previously selected choice. I have stored the choice in NSUserDefaults. How do I convert this int value to NSIndexpath and use it in my tableview?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

See the [NSINdexPath UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/index.html)

In your case you can use (Swift):

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate of [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454723/convert-nsinteger-to-nsindexpath)

I copied the recieved answer here

For an int index:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:index];
```

Creates Index of the item in node 0 to point to as per the reference.

To use the indexPath in a UITableView, the more appropriate method is

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourInt inSection:section];
```

Comment: This is ObjectiveC, not Swift

Comment: Fair enough, but it works the same. You can suggest an edit to my post with the swift code version. I bet there is an identical method ;)

Comment: He might as well post his own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You  can get indexpath using below code

```
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:YOURINTSTORED inSection:0];
```

Comment: This is ObjectiveC, not Swift